# What is the the Battle for Freljord secondary quest?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just seen this in a game of ARAM

[image]

I have a secondary objective, but have no idea how to complete it and what it would give me to complete it.

There was an ashe on my side and a Sejuani on the other, so I think it might be related to the storyline of Howling Abyss, but still, how do I complete the objective, and what does it give me?

Comment: I like how it's hard to capture a screenshot without a massive amount of raging in the chat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a great summary of how the quest works. You are correct in thinking it is due to the Ashe and Sejauni, and not due to it being on the Howling Abyss.

From the [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_for_Freljord):

> The event begins a seemingly random length of time after the following
>   conditions have been met, and can only occur once per game:
>
> - There must only be one Freljordian leader per team. Having 2 or more
>     will not cause the event to work.
> - The champions involved must have a sum of 20 kills + assists. (ex:
>     Sejuani has 3 kills and 17 assists. Adding them equals an exact 20.)
> - One Freljordian leader must be level 16 for the event to start.
>
> After a few seconds of meeting the said requirements, the event will
>   occur. The champions involved will say a unique quote at the start and
>   end of the event.
>
> The victor will be given a permanent buff called, Queen of the
>   Freljord, and an ice crown floating above her head.

To complete the event, one of the leaders must kill or assist in killing the opposing leader. Then you hear a unique taunt based on the participants (These can be viewed on the [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_for_Freljord))

Comment: Does the `Queen of the Freljord` buff provide additional stats?  Or is it just for bragging rights?

Comment: I believe it is just a flavor buff

Comment: @Toast, yea the video states it doesn't provide any stat bonuses.

Comment: There can be two freljord leaders per team, I had ashe on my side versus sejuani and lissandra and we got a quest fo ashe vs sejuani